# Python merge multiple list inside one variable into one list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a hard time putting multiple list into one because they are all inside one variable.

here is an exemple:

**What I have**

```
a = ['1'], ['3'], ['3']
```

---

**What I want**

```
a = ['1', '3', '3']
```

How can I resolve that using Python 3.x

---

**EDIT**

here is the code I'm working on.

```
from itertools import chain

def compteur_voyelle(str):
    list_string = "aeoui"
    oldstr = str.lower()
    text = oldstr.replace(" ", "")
    print(text)

    for l in list_string:
        total = text.count(l).__str__()
        answer = list(chain(*total))
        print(answer)

compteur_voyelle("Saitama is the One Punch Man.")
```

**Console Result :**

```
saitamaistheonepunchman.
['4']
['2']
['1']
['1']
['2']
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `itertools.chain`.

```
In [35]: from itertools import chain

In [36]: a = ['1'], ['3'], ['3']

In [37]: list(chain(*a))
Out[37]: ['1', '3', '3']
```

Or

```
In [39]: list(chain.from_iterable(a))
Out[39]: ['1', '3', '3']
```

Comment: I just tried it, the lists are still separated I posted the code above, am I missing something?

Comment: answer = list(chain(*total))
print(answer)  should be outside the for loop

Comment: @Hari I just get `['2']` instead of `['4', '2', '1', '1', '2']` if I put them outside.

Comment: @Sia Also `total` is a string, not a list of strings... . You probably can declare an empty list `answer = []` outside the loop, and just append to it on every iteration.

Comment: @Akavall it worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['1'], ['3'], ['3']

>>> type(a)
<class 'tuple'>
```

a is tuple here. we can covert tuple into list.

```
>>> a = ['1'], ['3'], ['3']
>>> [value[0] for value in list(a)]
['1', '3', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the same example as in other answers, i guess this can also be done using the **`sum`** *built-in* :

```
In [1]: a = [1], [3], [3]

In [2]: sum(a, [])
Out[2]: [1, 3, 3]
```